# Why can't I insert into my table variable in my stored procedure deleteByMonth, altough the query yields a result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, scope, transactions

I prepared the example below. I cannot populate the table `@ids` within the stored procedure `deleteByMonth`, although the query yields a result.
I think it is an issue related to variable scope of `@ids` or due to misuse of control flow statements. To my understanding `@ids` should be available within the scope of the stored procedure.
When I remove the `IF...ELSE` and `BEGIN...END` and `BEGIN TRANSACTION...COMMIT TRANSACTION` respectively (which I don't want to) `@ids` is populated and the `delete` statement is executed.
Why can't I insert into my `@ids` table variable?

```
create database test03;
go
use test03;
go

create table TestEntity (
testId bigint not null,
dateT datetime not null,
inGroup int not null,
done bit not null,
primary key(testId,dateT)
)

insert into TestEntity (testId, dateT, inGroup, done)
    values(99999,'2018-10-05',2,1)
insert into TestEntity (testId, dateT,inGroup, done)
    values(99999,'2018-09-01',2,1)
insert into TestEntity (testId, dateT,inGroup, done)
    values(77777,'2018-10-04',7,0)
insert into TestEntity (testId, dateT,inGroup, done)
    values(77777,'2018-08-01',7,0)

insert into TestEntity (testId, dateT,inGroup, done)
    values(88888,'2018-10-05',2,0)
insert into TestEntity (testId, dateT,inGroup, done)
    values(88888,'2018-09-01',2,0)
insert into TestEntity (testId, dateT,inGroup, done)
    values(88888,'2018-10-04',2,0)
insert into TestEntity (testId, dateT,inGroup, done)
    values(88888,'2018-08-01',2,0)
insert into TestEntity (testId, dateT,inGroup, done)
    values(3333,'2018-08-01',8,0)

insert into TestEntity (testId, dateT,inGroup, done)
    values(3333,'2018-10-01',8,0)

go


create function isDone (@id bigint)
    returns bit
    as
    begin
    declare @r int;
    declare @d int;
    select @r=sum(@@ROWCOUNT), @d=sum(cast(done as int)) from TestEntity
        where testId = @id and done = 1
        return IIF(@r=@d,1,0)
    end

go

CREATE procedure [dbo].[deleteByMonth]
(
    @month int
)
as

DECLARE @ids TABLE (t bigint not null)

BEGIN

        IF (@month is null or @month = 0)
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR('invalid month parameter!',11,1) RETURN;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                BEGIN TRANSACTION
                            insert into @ids 
                                select TestEntity.testId
                                    from TestEntity
                                    where
                                        (TestEntity.inGroup = 2 and dbo.isDone(TestEntity.testId) = 1)
                                group by
                                    TestEntity.testId
                                having
                                    (month(max(dateT)) <= @month)

                                delete from TestEntity where TestEntity.testId in (select t from @ids)

                COMMIT TRANSACTION
          END
END

select * from TestEntity
exec deleteByMonth 10
```

As `@@ROWCOUNT` was the problem I adapted the function as follows. It is my goal to compare the actual number of rows with the number of flags set for a `testId`

```
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[isDone](@id BIGINT)
RETURNS BIT
AS
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @r INT;
         DECLARE @d INT;
         select @r = r, @d= SUM(CAST(done AS INT)) from TestEntity ti 
            inner join (
     select COUNT(*) as r, testId from TestEntity 
        group by testId) as ton on 
        ti.testId = ton.testId 
        where ton.testId = @id group by ton.r

         RETURN IIF(@r = @d, 1, 0);
     END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `@@ROWCOUNT` as an argument to pass to the `dbo.isDone`. When it is passing its value is `0`, however, it gets value after `insert` statement. 0 value of `@@ROWCOUNT` makes the criteria in where clause returns no value.

Comment: @Alex It means that @@ROWCOUNT takes value after "insert" statement done. In "insert" statement it has the latest value that in your case is 0. After "insert" the value of @@ROWCOUNT will change to the value you need.

Comment: You can test it by 2 simple selects before and after the "insert" statement. --> "select @@ROWCOUNT"

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem! But when I select @@ROWCOUNT I always receive 1

Comment: I put the select @@ROWCOUNT before and after the insert statement. I see that @@ROWCOUNT is zero at first, but then it is 2. The number of rows in @ids are zero

Answer (score 1):

You can change your function as below:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[isDone](@id BIGINT)
RETURNS BIT
AS
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @r INT;
         DECLARE @d INT;
         SELECT @r = SUM(1), 
                @d = SUM(CAST(done AS INT))
         FROM TestEntity
         WHERE testId = @id
               AND done = 1;
         RETURN IIF(@r = @d, 1, 0);
     END;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

In funtion, you are using `@@ROWCOUNT`, but normal `COUNT(*)` would be enough.

Change `@r=sum(@@ROWCOUNT)` to `@r=sum(COUNT(*))`

Comment: Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.